# Best way for passing string while including file

Tags: php, session

I'm having a trouble with passing string while using include() function. I have index.php which serves as template file and is including any other pages.

For example, if I want to go to the home page, the address is http://somethingsomething.com/index.php?page=home and included file is pages/home.php. Bellow you can find how the template system works. I want to change  of the page you're currently are but I don't know what is the best way to pass that string from the title of the page. So if I'm on the Catalogue page - http://somethingsomething.com/index.php?page=catalogue, it will include file pages/catalogue.php and I've tried to pass string as SESSION but it didn't worked. Could you please help me?

Source URL: http://somethingsomething.com/index.php?page=catalogue

index.php file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome, world!</h1>
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 'home';
        }

        if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $page)) {
            $insert = include('pages/' . $page . '.php');
            if (!$insert) {
                $insert = include('pages/error.php');
            }
        } else if (empty($page)) {
            $insert = include('pages/error.php');
        } else {
            $insert = include('pages/error.php');
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

pages/catalogue.php file

```php
    <?php
        $title = "Catalogue";
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to include the file that defines $title BEFORE you use $title. I think that's the only issue here.

Comment: To clarify, currintly you're calling $ title at the very top, but it doesn't get defined until later when the include() function is called.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but how can I include it's content in the <body> section?

Comment: One way would be to use an output buffer up there... https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Can I maybe load it before I use $title and then just echo it in the body? Or is there better solution?

Comment: Determine the value of `$page` before you assign/use `$title`.  Then, use that value to get the value of `$title` from some mapping (static array, database, etc)

Comment: That way you'd dump any output from the include file into a variable, and echo that variable later in the code. Need me to flesh this out in an answer?

Comment: @Stevish That would be great, thank you. I have never worked with buffer.

Comment: You need to re-structure your code so that it is more logically organised.  If you have logic which defines the page content (i.e. title etc.) then determine this first and include the relevant code.

Comment: @NigelRen Are you suggesting something on how to, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
    ob_start();
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 'home';
        }

        if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $page)) {
            $insert = include('pages/' . $page . '.php');
            if (!$insert) {
                $insert = include('pages/error.php');
            }
        } else if (empty($page)) {
            $insert = include('pages/error.php');
        } else {
            $insert = include('pages/error.php');
        }
    $output = ob_get_clean();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome, world!</h1>
    <?php
        echo $output;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And that's it or should I somehow flush or end the buffering at the end?

Comment: `ob_get_clean()` basically turns off the output buffer after returning its contents, so nothing else needs to be done